# Need help to understand the basic concept of this

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Its may be a silly question but Can someone please explain how this works? ?
how to expand two terms where one is raised to some power and other is just 1?
the example is below.

[image]

This is what I want understand, for example (x^6 -1) = (x.x.x.x.x.x - 1) right? so how does it convert into (x^4 + x^2 + 1) (x^2 - 1)

Comment: You said, "mechanics behind". And tagged "number theory" and "prime numbers". But you never said anything about prime numbers or number theory in your question. I don't see what your question has to do with number theory. Are you working modulo something? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Yes it is is related to prime numbers of the form N= 2^n -1 where n must be prime otherwise if it is composite than this will produce N a composite number.

Comment: Perhaps this is more recognizable : $$1+x^2+x^4=\frac{1-(x^2)^3}{1-x^2}$$

Comment: this is what i want understand, for example (x^6 -1) = (x.x.x.x.x.x - 1) right? so how does it convert into (x^4 + x^2 + 1) (x^2 - 1)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing crazy about it. Let $y = x^k$, and then
$$x^{kl}-1 = y^l-1 = (y-1)(y^{l-1}+y^{l-2} + \cdots + y + 1).$$
The second equality comes from just expanding and seeing the terms in between cancelling out, or from doing a partial sum of a geometric sequence. Now changing $y$ back to $x^k$ would give you your formula.